# Google API User Credential code not executing in ASP .NET Core using .Net Framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am working on Google API (GMAIL) Integration to my client project using ASP .Net Core in .Net Framework 4.6.1 (Windows Application) using c#. I am unable to authenticate the gmail user credential, I have created .exe file for that application. Whenever I hit the service, the below code is not executing (not coming out of it and not coming exception too). I don't want to store credential file in local computer(removed FileDataStore from code).

```
UserCredential credential;
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
             new ClientSecrets
              {
                      ClientId = GetClientSecrets.ClientId,
                      ClientSecret = GetClientSecrets.ClientSecret
              },
              Scopes,
              Environment.UserName,
              CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

I have been trying from 2 weeks, but, none of the solution have helped me. Is it possible to do that using asp .net core..?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can't you use await instead of .Result? Using .Result in desktop UI app may lead to the deadlock.

Comment: Its almost never a good idea to use `.Result`, Desktop application or not. Exception behavior is different than `await` or `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`